# Java - Creating 3-Dimensional Data Structure

Tags: java, arraylist, vector, linked-list

I'd like to find out how I can create a 3-dimensional data structure to store object of `Pair <Integer, Integer>` with the following:

`Vector < ArrayList < LinkedList <Pair <Integer, Integer> > > > myData;`

Having that said,

1. How do I instantiate and construct an enpty data structure to store Pair objects?
2. How do I populate `myData` with 4 `Vectors`, each with 3 `ArrayList`, each with a 2 `LinkedList` of 5 Pair objects?

Comment: Your first question is unclear - which data structure do you want exactly to store the Pair objects in? I assume you have a `Pair` class? They are supposed to go in a `LinkedList` - so are you asking how to create an empty `LinkedList`, or what? Your second question too vague. What is the source of the data?

Comment: It is similar to single dimension. Start with `new Vector < ArrayList < LinkedList <Pair <Integer, Integer> > > >()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for this?

```
public class Main
{

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    Vector <ArrayList<LinkedList<Pair>>> myData = new Vector<ArrayList<LinkedList<Pair>>>(); //vector

    for (int i = 0; i <= 2; i++) { //ArrayList
      myData.addElement(new ArrayList<LinkedList<Pair>>());
      for (int j = 0; j <= 1; j++) { //LinkedList
        myData.get(i).add(new LinkedList<Pair>());
        for (int k = 0; k <= 4; k++) { //Pair
             myData.get(i).get(j).add(new Pair<Integer>(1 ,2));
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

class Pair<T> {
    T first;
    T second;

  public Pair(T first, T second) {
       this.first = first;
       this.second = second;
  }
}
```

With your declaration of myData it is only ONE vector. To have more vectors you need another data structure like `ArrayList<Vector<ArrayList<LinkedList<Pair>>>> myData`. Then you can add 4 vectors.